# How to get app reviews from Itunes

Tags: ios, itunes, review

I'm trying to get the app reviews/rating in iTunes to display in my website. The info in need includes: Review title, review description, number of star, time review, nick name of the reviewer.

Since I cannot have the actual URL of the app, I cannot get info as a normal HTML link.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

iTunes offers a reviews RSS feed that will return the last 500 reviews for any app:
http://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/customerreviews/id=364709193/xml

Note the reviews are specific to a storefront - so change out the "us" to the country code you want reviews for.

And the app ID referenced above can be found in the link to any app in the App Store.

Comment: You are correct Ted Hosmann. I used: http://itunes.apple.com/rss/customerreviews/id=533058384/json

Comment: For some reason the JSON version seems to omit the 'updated' field, which contains the date the review was left.

Comment: I get more than 500 reviews every time I request. Its somewhere between 600-700. I can not understand why.

Comment: is there any documentation where apple say only 500 reviews are made visible?

Answer (score 7):

In your [Itunes Connect](http://itunesconnect.apple.com) account

1-Go to your apps and select the desired app

2-Go to customers reviews

3-Get the RSS feeds for your app reviews[image]

Then you can easily included in your website